# Running HTML5 fullscreen in an app that doesn't allow them to exit

Tags: html, windows-xp

Working on an html5 app for a touchscreen windows xp computer that will be running in a store display. We need a good way of keeping users from exiting the program.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Kiosk mode" is what you need. [Here](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/) is some information regarding opera, but other browsers support it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You want to [Run Internet Explorer as the Shell](https://web.archive.org/web/20160220141708/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/embedded/archive/2005/03/30/403999.aspx), in Kiosk mode. You'll also want to set [NoBrowserClose](https://web.archive.org/web/20150311151230/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/823057) in the Registry. That's probably enough if somebody's around to restart it if IE crashes. Otherwise you should schedule a job to run every minute and re-launch IE if it isn't running.

Comment: I'm guessing IE will not be the target browser, considering the state of "HTML5" support.

Comment: Depends on what he needs. There's some HTML5 support there. He could run any browser he wants as the shell.